# Calculate center of mass using integration

Tags: integration

How to calculate center of gravity having figure described by those equations with integration? This can and should be solved by numerical analysis.

$y < -x + 1\\ y > x^2 - 1\\ y < \sin(x)$

[image]

Firstly I found bounding points for integration:

$-x + 1 = \sin(x) \\ x_0 = -0.63673265$

$sin(x) = -x + 1 \\ x_1 = 0.51097343$

$-x + 1 = x^2 - 1 \\ x_2 = 1$

Then I've calculated integral of $g(x)$ from $x_0$ to $x_1$:

$\int_{x_0}^{x_2} |x^2 - 1| dx = 1.2173486603176453$

Then integral of $h(x)$:

$\int_{x_0}^{x_1} |\sin(x)| dx = 0.32334348721908174$

Then integral of $f(x)$:

$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} |-x + 1| dx = 0.11957349302898969$

So the area between is equal to
$$\int_{x_0}^{x_1} |\sin(x)| dx + \int_{x_1}^{x_2} |-x + 1| dx - \int_{x_0}^{x_2} |x^2 - 1| dx = -0.7744316800695739$$

Which is something wrong I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

You have neatly found three roots as cutting points/limits $(x_0,x_1,x_2) $.

Next area evaluation of definite integrals by integrating the difference of the functions between two curves one at a time in between the limits you found.

$$ A= \int_{x_0}^{x_1} (h-g) dx +\int_{x_1}^{x_2} (f-g) dx $$

For x-moment

$$ \int_{x_0}^{x_1} x (h-g) dx +\int_{x_1}^{x_2} x (f-g) dx $$

Divide by A to get CG x coordinate.

For y-moment

Take ***average $y$*** between $ (h/g  \quad f/g) $ curves:

$$ \int_{x_0}^{x_1} y (h-g) dx +\int_{x_1}^{x_2} y(f-g) dx $$

Divide by A to get CG y coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the absolute values in the integrals when you're finding area. It's easier to explain why using two functions instead of three, so here's a Desmos graph of just $g(x)$ and $h(x)$:
[image]

Now, let's think about $\int_{x_0}^{x_2}g(x)dx$ and $\int_{x_0}^{x_2}h(x)dx$. Let's color the areas that the integrals measure: For the integral of $g$, let's color the *positive* area blue and the *negative* area red. For the integral of $h$, let's color the *positive* area green and the *negative* area orange:
[image]
Now, the region that we want to measure is the red area that is not orange, as well as the green area that is not blue. In order to properly capture the red area, we need to make sure we are *subtracting* the negative area in $\int g$ (giving a positive value) while *adding* the negative area in $\int h$ (which will eliminate the contribution of the orange region). Then we need to add the positive area in $\int h$ in order to get the green area while subtracting the positive area in $\int g$ to get rid of the blue area. So that means that in order to find the area between $g$ and $h$, we need to evaluate $\int_{x_0}^{x_2}h(x)-g(x)dx$.

Going back to the original issue, the area in between is $A=\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\sin x\,dx+\int_{x_1}^{x_2}-x+1\, dx-\int_{x_0}^{x_2}x^2-1\, dx$.

Then, to find the $x$-coordinate, you need to multiply the integrands by $x$:

$$x_{\text{CM}}=\frac 1A\cdot\left(\int_{x_0}^{x_1}x\sin x\,dx+\int_{x_1}^{x_2}x(-x+1)\, dx-\int_{x_0}^{x_2}x(x^2-1)\, dx\right)$$

The $y$-coordinate is similar but more difficult; with inverse functions it's essentially the same process.

Answer (score 1):

$A = \displaystyle \int_{x_0}^{x_2} (y_u - y_l) dx$ where $y_u$ is the upper bound of $y$ and $y_l$ is the lower bound of $y$. Even when $y$ is negative, please note that this difference will be positive.

$A = \displaystyle \int_{x_0}^{x_1} (\sin x - (x^2-1))dx + \int_{x_1}^{x_2} ((1 - x) - (x^2-1))  dx $

$A = \displaystyle \int_{x_0}^{x_1} \sin x \, dx + \int_{x_1}^{x_2} (1 - x) \, dx - \int_{x_0}^{x_2}(x^2-1) \, dx = -0.0682262 + 0.119573 - (-1.21735)$

$A \approx 1.2686968$.

Answer (score 0):

The lower border of the box around your graph is at about $y=-1.5$, but you're treating it like the $x$-axis.  Your first integral has little to do with your shaded area.  Better to

$$\int_{x_0}^{x_1}  \sin(x) - (x^2-1) \; dx + \int_{x_1}^{x_2}  -x+1 - (x^2-1) \; dx.$$